# vuejs: the correct path of local json file for axios get request

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

In my Vue project, I have mocked some data for next step development. I already save the test data in a `json` file. And my vue project is typical one created with Vue-Cli, and the structure for my project goes as following:

```
My_project
    build
    config
    data
        service_general_info.json
    node_modules
    src
        components
            component-A
                component-A.vue
```

as you can see, all the folders are created by the vue-cli originally. And I make a new folder `data` and place the test data json file inside.

And I want to read in the data by `axios` library in an event handling function inside the component of `component-A` as following:

```
  methods: {
    addData() {
      console.log('add json data...');
      axios.get('./../../data/service_general_info.json');
    },
  },
```

I use relative path to locate the target file.But get 404 error back. So how to set the path correctly? Currently I am running the `dev` mode in local host.

The error message is: `GET http://localhost:8080/data/service_general_info.json 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I'm afraid that you can not use [_axios_](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) like this! This library is for making **HTTP** requests but it seems you're trying to access _file-system_  instead which won't work as far as I know.

Comment: did u get any solution ?

Answer (score 10):

In Vue-cli project, `axios` can't get data from custom folder.

You should use `static` folder to save test json file.

So you should change `axios` call like this:

```
axios.get('/static/service_general_info.json');
```

This will get data from json.

Comment: is the `static` folder `assets` ?

Comment: No, `static` is different from `assets`.

Comment: You saved my life!

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing just for sake of testing then you can save it in public folder and access it directly on http root.

e.g. I have the file results.json in public folder then I can access it using http://localhost:8080/results.json

Comment: Yes, it is working with local but not with the build on the server.

Comment: check build output and adjust url accordingly.

Comment: Issue resolved, server not allowing .json format, just added mimeType in the web.config file and now it's working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For me it didn't work using static folder. I had to put it in **public** folder.

I put json folder in public & then accessed it like below.

```
getCountries() {
    return axios.get('json/country-by-abbreviation.json', { baseURL: window.location.origin })
        .then((response) => { return response.data; })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw error.response.data;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the http call is made from the server, axios has no idea that you're on http://localhost:8080, you have to give the full url.

Like this:

```
methods: {
    addData() {
      console.log('add json data...');
      axios.get('http://localhost:8080/data/service_general_info.json');
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, only the above solutions wouldn't work as it is being uploaded to a subdirectory. I found I needed to put it in the public/assets folder and use:

```
axios.get(process.env.BASE_URL+'assets/file.json')
```

While in vue.config.js I have set the local and live paths

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/path/to/app/'
    : '/'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply read a static JSON file using import. Then assign in data.

```
import ServiceInfo from './../../data/service_general_info.json';
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            ServiceInfo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will never work out of the box as json files do not have an export, therefore you would have to export * from the json file in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: Actually this works just fine. However it will be processed by webpack.